# Calling [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName:] with a custom font returns valid strings but using some of them in [UIFont fontWithName:size:] returns nil.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, ios7

**Summary**

I had been using custom fonts on an iOS project for a while, but recently, I did something (maybe changed a search header files) or something that makes it so that some fonts that I have included in the app aren't working anymore.

**The Facts**

a) The fonts are copied to the project and are assigned to the correct target.

b) They are copied in the copy bundle resources build phase.

c) They are in the info.plist assigned to the key "Fonts provided by application" with their full filename (including the extension, which in this case is .otf).

Here's the fun bit:

d) Calling [UIFont fontNamesForFamilyName] correctly returns all the fonts I have included.

e) Calling [UIFont fontWithName:size] with *some* of these strings returns nil.

**What have I tried?**

1) Erased Derived Data.

2) Reset the simulator.

3) Close/Opened Xcode.

4) Cleaned the build.

5) Removed the fonts from the project and info.plist.

**Please send help!**

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `fontWithDescriptor:size:` instead? Create a font descriptor with the custom font you need, and try with that.

Comment: I have. It failed (returns nil).

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this issue?